# Twillio programable video how to notify from client 1 to client 2

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I use `Video WebRTC Go` to build a peer to peer video chat app with `Twilio`.

Client 1 creates a room and gets access to that room. So how do we make client 2 aware of that this.
How do I pass the signal there is a call for him (Client 2).

Do I need to handle it my self? or Does Twillio provide a service to achieve that use case?

Hope my question is clear.

Any help!

Thanks in advance! =)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you create a room for the users to meet in you will need to make your users aware. There is nothing within Twilio Video specifically to do that.

There are service that Twilio provides that could be used for this, for example, you could SMS or email your user with a link to a page on your site where they can join the room. It depends on the user experience you want to create though.